# Setting reCAPTCHA Version 2 set another language other than English

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

[image]

How can I set this in another language, ie:. French

I've tried:

```
var RecaptchaOptions = {
     lang : 'fr',
  };
```

[Found above here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/customization)

Which does nothing.

I couldn't find relevant info under API Reference -> Version 2 on [Google Docs for reCAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro)

**Additional information:**

I'm using this on rails, with `gem "recaptcha"` [Found here](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/)

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You just need to specify the parameter "**?hl=**" in the script's url:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=fr'></script>
```

Not very well documented, indeed!

find your language code here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/language

Comment: [This seems to be the list of available language codes](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/language).

Comment: @ Syed - Where do you ge the language code from? Database? Query? And what language are you working with... PHP, ASP, ...

Answer (score 15):

If you are using the recaptcha gem you need to provide the **hl** param in **recaptcha_tags**.

Example:

```
<%= recaptcha_tags ssl: true, hl: 'it', display: { theme: 'white' } %>
```

Comment: Thanks! Neither well documented on the gem

Answer (score 5):

**Simple solution**

You can do it like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="captcha_container"></div>
<select id="ddllanguageListsGoogleCaptcha"></select>
```

**JS**

```
// Update language captcha 
function updateGoogleCaptchaLanguage(selectedLanguage) {

    // Get GoogleCaptcha iframe
    var iframeGoogleCaptcha = $('#captcha_container').find('iframe');

    // Get language code from iframe
    var language = iframeGoogleCaptcha.attr("src").match(/hl=(.*?)&/).pop();

    // Get selected language code from drop down
    var selectedLanguage = $('#ddllanguageListsGoogleCaptcha').val();

    // Check if language code of element is not equal by selected language, we need to set new language code
    if (language !== selectedLanguage) {
        // For setting new language 
        iframeGoogleCaptcha.attr("src", iframeGoogleCaptcha.attr("src").replace(/hl=(.*?)&/, 'hl=' + selectedLanguage + '&'));
    }
}
```

[**Online demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/7umzsmus/4/)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the "hl=*language code*" approach works well. The catch, of course, is to do this to EVERY instance of **`<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>`** on the page - both the one in the page head AND the one in the body. Only putting hl=... in the body leads to inconsistent results.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @ali-soltani for snipped! Did the thing! :)

I am providing my "vanilla" version for those who do not use jQuery, to save the few strikes.

```js
    function setCaptchaLang(lang) {

      const container = document.getElementById('captcha_container');

      // Get GoogleCaptcha iframe
      const iframeGoogleCaptcha = container.querySelector('iframe');

      // Get language code from iframe
      const actualLang = iframeGoogleCaptcha.getAttribute("src").match(/hl=(.*?)&/).pop();

      // For setting new language
      if (actualLang !== lang) {
        iframeGoogleCaptcha.setAttribute("src", iframeGoogleCaptcha.getAttribute("src").replace(/hl=(.*?)&/, 'hl=' + lang + '&'));
      }
    }
```